# Why is not displaying my list from my api on my react app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching a Fortnite API to see some details. I create an array that i will set to api data when i call setItemsArray method. But is not working!!!

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems()
    }, [])

    const [itemsArray, setItemsArray] = useState([])

    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.com/v1/map')
        const items = await data.json() 
        setItemsArray(items.data.pois)
        console.log(items.data.pois)
    }

    return (
        
        <div>
             <h1>Shop</h1>
             <div>
                 {itemsArray.map(el => {
                     <h1>{el}</h1>
                 })}
             </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is the `console.log` being called? what's the output (one or two elements are enough)?

Comment: yes the console.log is returning all data from api.

Comment: This is the output from console: Array(99) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not showing because you are not returning the data.
You can fix this using two options:

1. ```
    <div>
          {itemsArray.map(el => {
            return <h1>{el}</h1>
          })}
        </div>
   ```

````
2. ```

    <div>
          {itemsArray.map(el => (
            <h1>{el}</h1>
          ))}
        </div>
````